# construct a .jar from a folder

Tags: java, package

what I want is to regenerate  sdovis.jar complete file, I took mapbuilder.jar tool, after that I unzip it using winrar, the result contains a folder named oracle, and I want generate from that folder a .jar file in order to use it in a specific project.
Thank you.

Comment: A `.jar` is just a ZIP file with a specific internal structure; as you have discovered. Simply zip it up again.

Comment: @BoristheSpider it does not work if I zip an unziped .jar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(You have winRar!) This should work with any unsigned jar:

1. Extract "original.jar" to  (a new folder) `/modify`. (via context menu, or within a WinRar instance...the jar will open like a folder/zip/rar)
2. Apply your modifications to `/modify`.
3. (Per context menu/Or from within WinRar) Execute the "Add To Archive ..." dialog on `/modify`.

   - Use "ZIP" as the archiving format.
   - Rename the archive to "modified.jar".
   - Don't use a password!
   - Click Ok.

After this process and assuming that:

- orginal.jar was a valid/working jar before
- your modifications didn't break the validity (META-INF...) nor the functionality  (so were correct).

... you should have a valid & working "modified.jar"!

---

Of course WinRar is not obligatory and can be replaced by any other (working) zip or ([the](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html)) jar tool.